# How do I fetch a backbone.js model from serialized json from a mvc3 model?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

If I had a model like this in my MVC3 application:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Name Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

How would do I populate it with `.fetch()` from backbone.js?

This is what I tried:

```
class Person extends Backbone.Model

$ ->
    person = new Person()
    person.fetch()

    // person.get for things like Name.First, or Name, or First
    // all return undefined
    alert person.get( ... ) // ?
```

I have the appropriate JsonResult Action method and control, and have verified with Fiddler that the `fetch()` call is properly returning the Json data. (Which I can post tomorrow morning from the office)

I'm really new at Backbone, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you denormalize those properties to just be string representations of the class? For example `public Name Name { get; set; }` becomes `public string FullName { get; set; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple things: 1) fetch is async.  Try this:

```
person.fetch({
    success: function() {
        alert(person.get('Name')
    }
});
```

2) This will show that the name property is an object (but not a backbone model):

```
{
    Name: "Joe"
    etc...

}
```

You may want to use [Backbone.Relational](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331093300069&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational&ei=Md9WT5qfIsqztwec5sCTCQ&usg=AFQjCNHjBb0Ip589_RmpDg5L46pG7mHRpQ) or something similar if you want Name to be a backbone model.  or you can override [parse](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) to flatten out your json.