# How to bind data from server to Backbone.js's model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone.js, I have been following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-1/) and I am now comfortable with this tutorial, next what I wanted to do is, instead of setting the values from the javascript like as shown in the link [here.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-1/)

I want to pass values from server side, I have written the following code for this,

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
  {
      new Person(){Id = 1, FirstName = "Yasser", LastName = "Shaikh", City = "Mumbai"},
      new Person(){Id = 2, FirstName = "Adam", LastName = "Gilchrist", City = "Melbourne"},
      new Person(){Id = 3, FirstName = "MS", LastName = "Dhoni", City = "Ranchi"},
      new Person(){Id = 4, FirstName = "A", LastName = "Nesta", City = "Milan"},
  };

  public ActionResult GetTemplateData()
    {
        var jsonData = new
                       {
                       rows = (from m in people select new {
                               id = m.Id  ,
                               cell = new object[]
                                          {
                                              m.FirstName,
                                              m.LastName,
                                              m.City
                                          }
                               }).ToArray()
                       };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

for which I am trying to use `url` attribute, but I am just not able to understand how to go about this.

Please can some one guide me in getting this. Thanks !

**Update 1 :**

I am using the following javascript, please have a look, I have tried your suggested changes.. please help me fix this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    // data
    var contacts = [];

    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("TemplateDemo2", "Home")", function(data){
        contacts = data.rows;
    });

    // Model
    var Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:"@Url.Action("TemplateDemo2", "Home")"
    });

    // Collection
    var Directory = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Contact
    });

    // Individual contact view
    var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "div",
        className: "contact-container",
        template: $("#contactTemplate").html(),

        render: function () {
            var tmpl = _.template(this.template);

            $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    // Master View

    var DirectoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#contacts"),

        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new Directory(contacts);
            this.render();
        },

        render: function () {
            var that = this;

            _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
                that.renderContact(item);
            }, this);
        },

        renderContact: function (item) {
            var contactView = new ContactView({
                model: item
            });

            this.$el.append(contactView.render().el);
        }
    });

    // Instance
    var directory = new DirectoryView();

});
 </script>
```

and below is my text tempalte I am using

```
<script id="contactTemplate" type="text/template">
<div class="cc">
<h1><%= name %></h1>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: You have to debug a little bit, check where is the point your code starts to not doing what you expected. First test: _is your URL returning a proper JSON format and the mime-type is `application/json`_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to build a RESTful JSON api in your server layer. That means you need urls for all these HTTP requests:

- (verb) (mime-type) explanation
- (GET) (application/json) `url` returning all the models in an array
- (GET) (application/json) `url/:id` returning one model
- (POST) `url` that digests the *params*, create a model in the server and return the created model in json format
- (PUT) `url/:id` that digests the *params*, update a model in the server and return the updated model in json format
- (DELETE) `url/:id` that digest the *id param* and remove the model in the server

And, for convenience, the `url` has to be always the same. The server has to identify the differente actions by the `http-verb + existence(or not) of id param`.

Once you have this you just have to define this `url` in your Model like this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: <the url>
});
```

And your Collection like this:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyModel
});
```

Since here you will be allowed to use any *creation*, *updating* and removing Backbone command in your Collection or Model.

Answer (score 1):

If you're following the tutsplus tutorial, you will need something similar to:

```
(function ($) {

    var contacts = [];

    $.getJSON"/YourControllerName/GetTemplateData", function(data){
        contacts = data.rows;
    });

} (jQuery));
```

Which is just calling a controller action which is returning the JSON similar to what you have in Person class currently. Then you're just populating your view model with this JSON.

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594403/how-do-i-fetch-a-backbone-js-model-from-serialized-json-from-a-mvc3-model?rq=1) with good info

Let me know if you need more info or help :)